# Detect a change in the dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have an `authenticated` route with a dynamic segment `:slug` that is used as separate organizations' short names. Within each organization there are individuals and groups. It's possible that different organizations will have the same `individual IDs` and `group IDs`.

So the URLs `/bigcompany/s/individual/1` and `/smallcompany/s/individual/1` are both valid and will take you to the individual with ID=1 for each of those companies.

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('authenticated', { path: '/:slug' }, function() {
        this.resource('individual',  { path: 's/individual/:id' }, function() {
            ...
        });
        this.resource('groups', { path: 's/groups' }, function() {
            this.route('group', { path: ':id' });
        });
    });

    this.route('login', { path: ':slug/s/login' });
});
```

After I log in from `/bigcompany/s/login`, it takes me to `/bigcompany/s/individual/1` and loads the model for that individual.

The problem is that I can directly change the URL in the browser from `bigcompany` to `smallcompany` and it will go ahead and load the model for `/smallcompany/s/individual/1`.

Is there a way that if a user directly edits the URL in the browser to a different `:slug` that it will log the user out of the original `:slug` and load the login page for the new `:slug`?

Comment: If a user directly changes a url in the browser, the entire app is reloaded and whether or not the user is logged in to a different slug is dependent on the code in your route, your server, and even how you manage cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a JavaScript API to handle browser cookies called [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). When the user logs in to one organization I call

```
`Cookies.set('slug', credentials.slug);`
```

Then in the `authenticated` route I check that the current `:slug` in the URL matches the `slug` cookie.

If a user switches to a different `:slug` in the URL it will log the user out, transition to the login page of the new `:slug`, and remove the `slug` cookie.